# Add custom middleware in Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a lot of Blazor WebAssembly projects and soon I have to hire a company for the penetration tests. I run some test by myself (using for example https://observatory.mozilla.org) and the result is not great.

Usually, in an ASP.NET Core project, I added this code

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.GetTypedHeaders().CacheControl =
        new Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.CacheControlHeaderValue()
        {
            MustRevalidate = true,
            NoCache = true,
            NoStore = true,

        };

    context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy", 
        "default-src 'none'; " + "script-src 'self'; " + 
        "connect-src 'self'; " + 
        "img-src 'self'; " + 
        "style-src 'self'; " +
        "base-uri 'self'; " + 
        "form-action 'self'; " + 
        "frame-ancestors 'none';");

    return next.Invoke();
});
```

that at least marches with some recommendation. The problem I face is in Blazor WebAssembly with .NET6 there is no extension `Use`

```
var app = builder.Build();
app.Use(..); // doesn't exists
```

So, I think I have to create a middleware for it but I can't find how.

PS: I tried to create an ASP.NET Core hosted project for the Blazor WebAssembly but I ended up to face the same issue.

Comment: Are you "penetration testing" your WASM code or the API that your application interfaces with?  The API you test as a DotNetCore application which is what it is.  The WASM code is basically "Open Source".  Its compiled, but anyone with the right tools can run run your app, get the WASM code and de-compile it.

Comment: Blazor WebAssembly runs in the Browser, Middleware runs on a Server. The Hosted project is the right approach. And then find the right Program..cs .

Comment: Thank you @HenkHolterman I use the ASP.NET Core hosted but there are some issues with the authentication

Comment: Thank you @MrCakaShaunCurtis I'm testing the UI because I like to be compliant to the OWASP recommendation

Comment: There is a post here https://www.puresourcecode.com/dotnet/blazor/add-security-headers-to-blazor-webassembly/ that helps to improve the header security.